# replacing the value with previous row value based on condition in R

Tags: r

I am trying to clean some data that I have.

Current format has 4 variables (id, speaker, text, and dup):

```
id speaker text dup 

1 GHS how are you 0 

2 yea yea 1 

3 CHA where is it 0 

4 CHA I cant find it 0 

5 CHA did you 0 

6 what what 1 

7 CHA did you find it 0
```

dup is a variable i created to flag all instances where speaker=text. When this is true, I want to replace speaker with the value of the row above it (See row 2 and 6)

DESIRED FORMAT:

```
id speaker text dup 

1 GHS how are you 0 

2 GHS yea 1 

3 CHA where is it 0 

4 CHA I cant find it 0
 
5 CHA did you 0 

6 CHA what 1 

7 CHA did you find it 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `replace` values in 'speaker' to NA based on the 'dup' and then `fill` it with the previous non-NA value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(speaker = replace(speaker, as.logical(dup), NA)) %>%  
  fill(speaker)
#  id speaker            text dup
#1  1     GHS     how are you   0
#2  2     GHS             yea   1
#3  3     CHA     where is it   0
#4  4     CHA  I cant find it   0
#5  5     CHA         did you   0
#6  6     CHA            what   1
#7  7     CHA did you find it   0
```

---

Or in a single step with `na.locf0` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df$speaker <- with(df, na.locf0(replace(speaker, as.logical(dup), NA)))
```

---

Or if there are only a single cases,

```
with(df, ifelse(dup ==1, lag(speaker), speaker))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:7, speaker = c("GHS", "yea", "CHA", "CHA", 
"CHA", "what", "CHA"), text = c("how are you", "yea", "where is it", 
"I cant find it", "did you", "what", "did you find it"), dup = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun! This seemed to work for what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Grab the indexes of the flagged rows `c(2,6)`, and then fill them in with the prior row `c(2,6) - 1 == c(1,5)`. You already have the `dup` column, but to be clear:

```
sel <- which(dat$speaker == dat$text)
dat$speaker[sel] <- dat$speaker[sel - 1]
```